# Geographic coordinates; Different latitude & longitude format?

Tags: coordinate-system, geoprocessing, format

I am having trouble identifying what format these coordinates are in. Is it DMS?

```
Latitude    Longitude
N49-46.7    W086-56.4
N51-28.7    W000-27.7
N40-51.0    W074-03.6
N01-21.6    E103-59.4
```

How do I change it to decimal?

Comment: This looks like degrees & decimal minutes. To get decimal degrees just divide the minutes by 60. So, 86-56.4 becomes 86.94

Comment: `W086-56.4` becomes **-86.94** (`W` and `S` need negation)